# What is an alternative for "until now" in this context?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, alternatives

Actually the title is not exactly what I mean, but I cannot find a better way to describe this question.

Consider this sentence:

> That's the only response I've got for my question ____.

If I put "until now" in there, I think it means:

> Even though there was only one answer, now there are two (or more).

However, what I really want to say is:

> Even now, there's still only one answer.

Is there a word or phrase to put in the blank for the intended meaning?

Comment: "even now" works pretty well.

Comment: @Adam Is there another choice that stresses "until", "for such a long period of time".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idiomatic phrase here is *so far*:

> 2: up to the present
>   // has written one novel *so far*

(source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/so%20far))

'Far' implies it has been a considerable amount of time, and the entire phrase indicates you could expect more in the future (but it's by all means not certain).

Comment: Thanks. One more question: since _so far_ is explained as _up to the present_, can I use that too? And what about _up to now_ and _up till now_?

Comment: Yes, but it's less idiomatic. *Up to now* would work too. The difference between *up to* and *until* is that *up to* usually includes its 'subject', and *until* usually not. (Though there are certainly exceptions.)

Comment: Uh...what do you mean by a subject? An example would be great.

Comment: Example: the difference between *up to December 31st* and *until December 31st* is that the first one includes December 31st, and the second one does not.

Comment: I see what you mean. Thanks again for the clarification.